# Array of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to generate dynamic buttons based on the array elements that I have.
I am able to generate the buttons but the array that I have used has objects instead of array elements.  The buttons json array i need to use to track of button status and other computation.  Can you help changing the code to have array element instead of objects?

```
var cars = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$scope.btns = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i) {
 if(cars[i]!== 4 && cars[i]!==5)
  {
   $scope.btns.push({label: cars[i]+"/0/0", state: false });
   $scope.btns.push({label: cars[i]+"/0/1", state: false });
  }
}
console.log($scope.btns);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kiranmca04/9j79djew/3/

```
current output:
 [Object { label="1/0/0",  state=false}, Object { label="1/0/1",  state=false}, Object { label="2/0/0",  state=false}, Object { label="2/0/1",  state=false}, Object { label="3/0/0",  state=false}, Object { label="3/0/1",  state=false}, Object { label="6/0/0",  state=false}, Object { label="6/0/1",  state=false}]

Expected:
 [{ label="1/0/0",  state=false}, { label="1/0/1",  state=false}, { label="2/0/0",  state=false}, { label="2/0/1",  state=false}, { label="3/0/0",  state=false}, { label="3/0/1",  state=false}, { label="6/0/0",  state=false}, { label="6/0/1",  state=false}]
```

Comment: By using { ... } you are creating "Object"s .. not buttons. Do you mean an HTML button? What is $scope.btns anyway?

Comment: Maybe because you put objects in it, it's just a wild guess though.

Comment: @Bálint haha. What are you trying to achieve with the resulting array? You are getting the expected output here?

Comment: from what I see you are putting objects so the output is correct. Can you explain you final goal?

Comment: I have a requirement to display buttons based on the services list that I get from my rest call.  the user will be shown with list of option avialable in button format.  Buttons are going to have toggle feature to select or unselect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dev tools isn't showing you serialized JSON because it has more powerful features. If you want to see what the JSON representation of your array would look like you can use `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.btns));`, but this is largely unnecessary, as you already have the appropriate structure.

Comment: Thank you zzzzBov.  i am able to see what i want.